# Why Do I Only Receive The Uri String When Serializing A Uri Using JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, uri, system.text.json

I'm sure this is a 'wrong question' but here goes!

I'd like to serialize Uri properties in Json format.

However, when I attempt to do something like:

`var jsonResults = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(uri);`

All I get in return is the actual Uri string, not its properties and values.

According to documentation like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0

It should serialize properties of the object into the string with their names and values, unless I've completely misunderstood something.

I've kind of made a unsophisticated method of doing this using string builder to show you the values I'm talking about. They would be these:

> [Uri Result Data]
>
> Absolute Uri:    [https://westmd.craigslist.org/]
>
> Absolute Path:   [/]
>
> Scheme:          [https]
>
> Host:            [westmd.craigslist.org]
>
> Port:            [443]
>
> Path & Query:    [/]
>
> DnsSafeHost:     [westmd.craigslist.org]
>
> Authority:       [westmd.craigslist.org]
>
> Fragment:        []
>
> Scheme & Server: [https://westmd.craigslist.org]
>
> IdnHost:         [westmd.craigslist.org]
>
> Default Port:    [True]
>
> Host Name Type:  [Dns]
>
> User Info: []
>
> [Uri Segments]:

However, when using the line of code above, for JsonSerialization, all it returns is..

```
[JSON]: "https://westmd.craigslist.org/"
```

Based on the documentation I've read, and stack articles I've read, the JsonSerialization should have these properties and their values, even if un-indented by default.

I've simply used the function laid out in the MSDN documentation and expected results similar to the ones shown,

`string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);`

With results of..

> {"Date":"2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00","TemperatureCelsius":25,"Summary":"Hot"}

as per [The MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0)

I'm not sure if there's a specific methodology or a different way you have to go about this with a Uri than other objects, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Selvin 
That's the objective, is to have it serialize the class with the properties and their values, not just the string representation of the Uri.

Comment: Ah, okay, no problem. It happens. I knew the serializer required the [JsonProperty] attribute for serializing readonly or private get's, but as I have no control over the Uri class, is there an alternative? @Selvin (That may actually be the wrong name of the attribute, but you know..)

Comment: But there's obviously properties within that object, it's not just the string, I'm not sure what you mean but using another object not making sense? I'm a little confused, sorry. It would be helpful if stack showed you comments added before you add one so you know you're responding to the right thing..

Comment: It's never converted to string, it's passed directly as the Uri object from the out parameter of Uri.TryCreate, and I know I can access these properties through it.. I just feel like I should be able to do it in a more sophisticated way such as Json Serialization than adding these properties to a string one at a time..

Comment: I'm not trying to recreate it or want a class for it, I just want to output the properties listed to a string, and I like Json's format..

Comment: Welp, you're a wonderful human being and I'm sorry my question has made you so angry. Quite frankly it seems like you don't understand it, so I'm not sure why you're yelling at me. If you know a way to get the Uri object's properties and values into a Json string so it's pretty, please do let me know. :)

And then you delete all your comments? Why act that way in the first place then..? People should not have to have anxiety about asking a question because people act like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a hidden `Uri` converter somewhere in c# code that uses `ToString()` representation, like `System.UriTypeConverter`, explaining the output format.

These properties you want are in fact useless, cause most of them like `AbsoluteUri` have no setter, meaning you won't be able to deserialize them ;)

If you absolutely want a custom serialization/deserialization of this framework object, you will have to code your own converter, but I'm not sure this is a good idea.

If this is the case, look at `JsonConverter<T>` base class you will have to inherit from.

Here a startup for serializing at your convenience

```
public class UriConverter : JsonConverter<Uri>
{
    public override Uri? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Uri value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WriteString("absoluteUri", value.AbsoluteUri);
        writer.WriteNumber("port", value.Port);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
var converter = new UriConverter();

options.Converters.Add(converter);

var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:9044/admin");
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(uri, options);
```

Comment: There is indeed a hidden built-in `Uri` converter.  It's here: [UriConverter.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/UriConverter.cs).  What it writes is `writer.WriteStringValue(value.OriginalString);`, and when reading, does `Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out Uri? value)`.

Comment: You're the man! I know they're useless, truthfully.. I honestly have no intention of using them. I'm just making a scraping application and it was to satisfy my curiosity. Up next, displaying all the data from HttpResponseMessage :D Thanks for the help.

<para/> Edit: I apparently don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I'll remember this.

Comment: @dbc You're also the man <3 I wonder why it's hidden..?